# How to print a specific part of directory path in powershell

Tags: powershell

My script is running in a loop on files and I display the path for each file but the path is too long and I want to display only the relevant directory. the path build always the same
examlpe for output path:

```
$File.DirectoryName
C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239\IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119\IDUDatabase
```

I am creating the temp folder and the sub folder as below:

```
$tempFolder = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) (New-GUID).ToString('n')
$subTemp = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath ([datetime]::Now.Ticks)
```

So this part is constant `C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239`

I want to display only the 'IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119\IDUDatabase'
The structure is always the same except the user name (C:\User\UserName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a prefix from a string you can use the `Substring` method…

```
$subTemp = "C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239"

$mypath = Join-Path -Path $subTemp -ChildPath "IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119\IDUDatabase"

$displayPath = $mypath.Substring($subTemp.Length+1)

$displayPath
# IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119/IDUDatabase
```

Note the `+1` is there to remove the path separator immediately after the folder prefix.

Comment: Hi @mclayton. the script is very long and I can't change the logical inside 
What I have in my hand is the full path only but I am holding the $subTemp maybe I can do with him something to get only the directory I need?

Comment: @bandit - if there are constraints within your environment can you edit your question to include the details.

Comment: ($file.DirectoryName).Substring($subTemp.Length+1) did the job

Answer (score 2):

You might use the [Resolve-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) [-Relative](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path#-relative) parameter for this:

```
Set-Location $subtemp
GCI $subtemp -Recurse |Foreach-Object { Resolve-Path -Relative $_.FullName }

.\IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119
.\New folder
.\IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119\IDUDatabase
.\New folder\New Text Document.txt
```